# Incompatibility using managed array and std:array at same time

Tags: .net, arrays, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have my C++/CLI code using arrays like this (for example):

```
array<String^>^ GetColNames() { 
    vector<string> vec = impl->getColNames();
    array<String^>^ arr = gcnew array<String^>(vec.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) { 
        arr[i] = strConvert(vec[i]); 
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

It's compiling fine until I add the library "array" to the project:

```
#include <array>
```

Then I don't know how to use the managed CLI array, because the compiler thinks that all the declared arrays are the `std::array`.

Errors examples:

```
array<String^>^ arr
//           ^ Error here: "too few arguments for class template "std::array""

gcnew array<String^>(vec.size())
//    ^ Error: "Expected a type specifier"
```

How to solve this? I tried removing `using namespace std` from that file, but it makes no difference. Should I remove that from every other C++ file on the project?

Comment: c++-cli is most certainly not C++.

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`? See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: You've got `using namespace std;` You get what you deserve :)

Comment: @Aschratt jrok: Already tried that (removing `using namespace std` from that file). Same errors when including <array>

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Clearly you have a `using namespace std;` in scope somewhere.  Watch out for it being used in .h file if you cannot find it.

You can resolve the ambiguity, the C++/CLI extension keywords like *array* are in the `cli` namespace.  This compiles fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <array>

using namespace std;         // <=== Uh-oh
using namespace System;

int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto arr = gcnew cli::array<String^>(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Certainly, that was the problem. Removing it only from the C++/CLI file was not enough. Thanks. Your second option works fine as well, but I decided to remove the `using namespace std` everywhere in my project.